# Techniques on how to export large CSV file with Symfony

Tags: php, file, symfony, csv

I have a task to export 100,000 rows of records from my database to csv format.

What are the best approaches on doing this? I am totally clueless on what to search and study.

I want to have chunk downloads like the other sites with PART format while the download is not yet finished and at the same time do not let my server be exhausted.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759418/download-large-csv-file-to-browser-while-it-is-being-generated I like http://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/connections/output/#outputting-the-document-into-chunks.

Comment: I will definitely look at it thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [StreamedResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation.html#streaming-a-response) from Symfony HttpFoundation component combined with [Doctrine iterate](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-large-results-for-data-processing).

Something like this:

```
$response = new StreamedResponse(function () {
    $data = $this->myQuery()->iterate();
    $csv = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
    while (false !== ($line = $data->next())) {
        fputcsv($csv, [$line[0]->column1], ';');
    }
    fclose($csv);
});
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.csv"');
```

Comment: Fantastic! This has been the ONLY answer I found, after a lot of searches, that generates a CSV file without having to deal with Twig. Thanks!!!

Comment: GREAT answer ! But I had to use a `if (isset($line[0]))` inside the `while` loop

Answer (score 3):

Based on @G1.3's answer, here is the updated code for Doctrine 2.11+ (the latest version now, 25.05.2022.) and Symfony 5.4:

```
class CsvExportController extends AbstractController
{
    public function downloadCsv(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
    ): StreamedResponse {
        $response = new StreamedResponse(function () use ($entityManager) {
            $csv = fopen('php://output', 'w+');
            fputcsv($csv, [
                'your',
                'csv_headers',
                'go_here'
            ]);
            $query = $entityManager->createQuery('SELECT t FROM Your\Entity\Class t');
            /**
             * @var \Your\Entity\Class $row
             */
            foreach ($query->toIterable() as $row) {
                fputcsv($csv, [
                    $row->getYourDataField01,
                    $row->getYourDataField02,
                    $row->getYourDataField03
                ]);
                // detach from Doctrine, so that it can be Garbage-Collected immediately
                $entityManager->detach($row);
            }
            fclose($csv);
        });
        
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.csv"');
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'no-store');

    return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way:

> Controller Function:

```
private function downloadCSV(QueryBuilder $query): Response
    {
        $csv = $this->renderView('templates/csv/template.csv.twig', [
            'data' => $query->getQuery()->getResult(),
        ]);

        // crafting response
        $response = new Response($csv);

        $disposition = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            sprintf('file_%s.csv', time()));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $disposition);

        return $response;
    }
```

> Render CSV in template:

```
{% set header = [
    'Internal Id',
    'title',
    'url'
] %}
{{ str_putcsv(header) }}
{% for i in data %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set row = [
        i.id,
        i.title,
        absolute_url(path('route_to_post', { data: i.id }))
    ] %}
{% endspaceless %}
{{ str_putcsv(row) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer is interesting, can you explain what the `str_putcsv` function does ?